# HTTP Native Plugin (IONIC 3)

Tags: json, http, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I'm trying to make a post request using the HTTP cordova plugin. However, for some reason, the JSON data consumed by the Server side is not being formatted correctly (json brakets). Could anyone help me please?

The import:

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';
```

The request implementation:

```
public sendData(sufix, json) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        this.http.post(URL+sufix, JSON.stringify(json), {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}).then(result => {
            resolve(result.data);
        }).catch(error => {
            reject(error);
        });

    });
}
```

The json sended:

> {name: 'Test'}

The content received by the server:

> =%7B%22name%22%3A%22Test%22%7D

The server implementation:

```
@Path("/register")
public class RegisterEndPoint {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response registerUser(UserDTO userDTO) {

        // Create DAO for persistence
        FactoryDAO factory = new FactoryDAO();
        UserDAO userDAO = factory.getUserDAO();

        // Create user to be persisted
        if (!userDAO.userExist(userDTO.getEmail())) {

            User user = new User();
            user.setPassword(userDTO.getPassword());
            user.setEmail(userDTO.getEmail());
            user.setName(userDTO.getName());
            userDAO.persist(user);
            userDAO.commit();
            return Response.status(200).build();

        }
        return Response.status(405).entity(new ErrorDTO("User already registered!")).build();

    }


}
```

Comment: Just add this.http.setDataSerializer(‘json’) before do the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be in Native Plugin, so I've changed to the angular http solution, and it works fine. Follow below the solution which I've perform. Thanks everyone who helped me.

The imports required:

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from  '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';
```

AuthProvider:

```
public sendRequest(sufix, json) {

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(URL+sufix, json, options)
        .timeout(TIMEOUT_REQUEST*1000)
        .do(this.logResponse)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError)

}

private logResponse(res: Response) {
    console.log(res);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    return res.json();
}

private handleError(res: Response | any) {
    return Observable.throw(res.json().error || 'Fail to connect to the server');
}
```

Calling the AuthProvider:

```
this.authProvider.sendRequest('register', this.signup).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('Success!');
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Providers included in app.module.ts

```
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

Comment: did you ever try to use ionic native again? we have the same problem! The data could not be post to server.

Answer (score 1):

can you please try sending the body without making it a string. you can send the JSON Object without stringify. Give it a try :)

**UPDATE
After sending this

```
{name: 'Test'}
```

If you are getting `name = "test"`

Why dont you try like this

```
var data =  JSON.stringify(data);
var obj = {data:data};
//send the obj Object
```

So it will show as data = "{name:test}"

Now Parse it from the server. Try and let me know :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I've tried, but the result was 'name="Test"', without json pattern

Comment: Thank you again, it doesn't work =(. "data=%7B%22name%22%3A%22Test%22%7D"

Comment: how are you parsing this from the server ?

Comment: It is a Java Server. I'm using Rest technology (Jersey framework). It turns out that sending the request via Java Client, this behavior doesn't happen, I don't think it's a parse problem.

Comment: hi @PedroDurek , this is not an issue with the Ionic Plugin, this is from your server side. Il check on Jersey Framework and let you know :)

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much =)

Comment: can you provide me your code for this POST method ?

Comment: I posted it. what I've tried to do was to substitute the userDTO object to a String variable on method's parameter, and the results were what I've shown above.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to make post request using HTTP then try sending request in this format.

`let body = new FormData();
body.append('name', 'Test');
this.http.post(<url>,body);`

Try and lemme know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but unfortunately, it didn't work, the server has received a blank string.

Comment: Try it using-- import {Http} from ''@angular/http''

Answer (score 1):

Just add this.http.setDataSerializer(‘json’) before do the post